# Django admin - prepopulating field using data of another object

Tags: django-models, django-admin

Suppose I have two models: Product and Contract. Product has field price, Contract has field price too. And Contract has ForeignKey(Product) field. When choosing the ForeignKey(Product) field of Contract (suppose ProductX was chosen) I want to automatically fill field price of Contract with the same value as the field price of ProductX object. How can it be implemented?

Comment: please elaborate. are you looking for a way to do this in django? an sql query? probably you just want the field price field once in it's own table, and have the other tables refer to it.

Comment: I thought about doing it in admin.py somehow. When creating new Contract object via django administration I choose certain product (ForeignKey(Product)) field, which has it's own price. I want field price of of the Contract take the same value automatically and display it in form.